# Child Component with structural directive (*ngif) is always executed last despite being placed ahead in the Parent Component html

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template, angular-directive, angular-structural-directive

I was working on a app where I encountered a peculiar case. For simplicity I have created a sample app and tested this although the behaviour was same.

**Sample app:**

In the parent component(my-app) I have the same child component with *ngIf and without it. The condition in *ngIf is mentioned upfront but despite it as you can see the method [check()]  associated with it is executed last.

[image]

**Excepted:** The Method Check() should execute first and then Check2()

Comment: and the problem is?

Comment: The check() is executed after check2()

Comment: yes for obvious reasons. That is how it should work

Comment: @Dalorzo: elaborate?

Comment: structural directives create embedded view, which is somewhat a child of a current view and because of that will be executed later

Comment: @Andrei IMO directives don't have a view, though when dig deeper it found out the structural directive use a function called _updateview() as mentioned in this link https://itnext.io/the-in-and-outs-of-angular-ngif-2bc3ca7bc0fe

Comment: do you see `createEmbeddedView` even in the article that you've mentioned? that is what I meant

Comment: so it's executed later but remembered the place to render. isn't there a legit way to customize it or delay subsequent executions until it itself resolves. @Andrei